# how do i query the subcollection comments data as i need to show it in the feedback list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently building a Project using Firestore database which has a feedback document, each feedback has its title,detail and upvotes, along with it has a subcollection because those comments will have further replies.

How should i query the comments in such a manner that they i would be able to show them along with the feedbacks, as i need to show them along with feedbacks as a list and show the comments length with it.

let me first explain the structure of the document, there is a feedback document, each feedback  has a feedbacktitle, feedbackdetail and upvote field, i had to make the comment a subcollection as they would also have a further replies subcollection.

My current Problem is how can i query my subcollection

```
  onSnapshot(feedbacksCol, async snapshot => {
  const data = snapshot.docs
  const docs = data.map((d) => ({
    id: d.id,
   ...d.data(),
    comment: ??//      
  setCurrentFeedbacks(docId)
})
```

How can i get the count of comments subcollection and directly store it in the comment propery? is there any way to do that

The above is able to get me the feeback collection, but how can i query the subcollection inside it,as i need to show the length of comments along with the feedbacks, I want to get the number of comments against each feedback and store them in the same object as i need to show the count of comments in each feedback

The structure of the document looks like this

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the response!, I have tried to explain the issue i am facing more briefly, looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have updated my question hope it was descriptive looking forward to your answer!

Comment: My answer shows how to get the comments or the comment count. Did you try that code yet? What happened when you did? Was there an error message? --- If you got stuck while implementing what I showed, please edit your question to include an additional code snippet that shows what you did with the information in my answer and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

To read the document from the `comments` subcollection you can do:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "feedbacks", d.id, "comments"));
```

Here the `d.id` is the ID for the `feedbacks` document whose comments you want to read.

---

To [get the count of documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) in a specific `comments` subcollection, you can call `getCountFromServer` instead of `getDocs`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the problem is how do i save it in one go like above i am making an id property, how can i do the same on comment such that it holds the count of comments, as since it's async await, is there a way to do the same

Comment: First off: which of the two options are you trying to get to work? --- You can call either `getDocs` or `getCountFromServer` inside the `onSnapshot` callback you have. If that doesn't work for you, it might be helpful if you edit your question to show the code of where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks again , My goal is to get the number of comments in the subcollection which will give the count of comments, but how can i directly do it in one execution as i am storing my Id along with other data , i want to have a comment property and directly store the count of comment there